# Can browser talk to already running Java Web Start application?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'd like my web page to talk to an already running Web Start application and I need the communication latency to be less than a second even on a slower machine.

I've done quite a bit of research and there seems to be 2 solutions.

1. Talk via a web server. For example, the workflow would be: the web page makes a request to the server with new parameters for the JWS app -> the server caches the request -> the Java Web Start app keeps polling the server for new requests.
2. Use SingleInstanceService and simply launch the app again with new parameters. SingleInstanceService will ensure that only one instance is running. However, this is slow because you still need to go through JVM every time you want to pass new arguments and it takes a second or two on my machine.

Is there a way to maintain a live communication between a web page and a JWS application so that new arguments can be passed to the app more or less instantly?

Comment: What does the _"Java Web Start app"_ do? Isn't implementing a web service to receive the request and than invoke the _"Java Web Start app"_ via RMI a cleaner solution?

Comment: The JWS app is just a simple program that is as simple as a calculator. However depending on the input parameters, it could do things differently.
Your suggestion about RMI seems similar to my solution #1 although I am not familiar with how RMI works. It still seems to use a web server for communication. I am wondering if there's a better or faster way.

Comment: By the way, does RMI work for Java Web Start apps as well?

Comment: pretty sure it's doable. Why don't you just try it out? Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into RMI. However, I am not trying to optimize anything. The latency of less than 1 sec is a requirement. And currently any server side work takes too long to consider for our system. So I was looking for a simpler answer.